# Coral Bark Japanese Maple in Toronto

Tags: japanese-maple

I just bought this for $130 from a nursery (reduced because it was the last year stock) This year's stock had greenish colors for bark an the leaves totally green. It is almost 9' long (the longest branch-did not fit in the picture)

Here are my questions:
-is there anybody living in Toronto who has this tree ?
-would it be a good idea to move it in a big pot and find the best spot for him for the rest of the year and then move it in a corner where it can sit for the winter wrapped and sheltered from wind and cold temperatures ?
-for how long can you keep a tree like this in a big pot without crippling the tree's growth ?
-is it practical to consider that at maturity I would still be able to wrap it in burlap?

[image]

Comment: As I said I just bought the tree. All of them in the nursery were about the same size and had the same temporary pot. I guess it is to save money and  they assume that the tree will be planted.

Comment: Can you not find a place to plant it in the ground?

Comment: Yes I can but It is a complicated situation. This is a very sensitive tree and I am stubborn person. I think that with proper care and thoughtful selection of the place of the tree it can find a place in my backyard and it can be an attraction. Before I pull the trigger I would like to test (if possible) if the tree is OK with it. I will post a separate question for that showing the layout and the wind directions (wind rose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its perfectly hardy in your area - it just needs a spot that isn't incredibly windy and doesn't bake too much in all day sun during summer if your summer temperatures are regularly quite high, although the primary concern would be wind exposure. Trying to keep it going in a pot isn't really a good idea, it's not a small nor particularly slow growing Acer palmatum variety, with an ultimate height of between 4 to 8 metres, and its pretty tall already. The roots will also be more vulnerable to cold in a pot. More information on this tree here https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=31

Comment: I am not 100 percent sure about that hardiness. I have read tens of reports saying that the tree is particularly prone to die backs during the winter.

Comment: Its not usually cold that causes that, and dieback is extremely common in most Acers, particularly japanese acers, and can happen in pots too.

Comment: I am worried about wind and sun ..see here https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/33005/coral-bark-japanese-maple-where-to-plant-it-to-avoid-cold-winter-wind-and-hot-s